# how to convert NTFS to ext4 in windows?

Tags: filesystems, partitioning, ntfs, ext4

I want to convert one partition of my windows which is NTFS (or can be FAT32) to a linux file system partitioning?
I'm looking for some tools or ways to do it for me!

Comment: Are there files on this partition?

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, there's no way to convert NTFS to ext4. These two FSs store information in much different way. Maybe what you can do is to move those files somewhere, then format the partition to ext4 and move them back.

Comment: To expand on hexchain's idea, shrink the ntfs partition using a partition manager like gparted, make a ext4 partition, copy the files, delete the NTFS partition, expand the ext4 partition. But if you have a second drive/computer you can copy to, I would recommend using the 2nd drive instead.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Wouldn't that take too much time to expand partition ...?

Comment: Yes, which is why I recommend using a 2nd drive if it is a option, but some people do not have access to a second drive or computer.

Comment: OK how could I do that in windows?

Comment: @aakpro Get a partition software, like Partition Magic.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there IS a way to do this. But unfortunately, only in Linux.

You could easily convert NTFS to ext2 or ext3 with the software [**anyconvertfs**](http://anyfs-tools.sourceforge.net/man8/anyconvertfs.8.html) from [anyfs-tools](http://anyfs-tools.sf.net/)

Then you could convert it to ext4 using [*tune2fs*](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs)

Comment: This is a great idea... he can boot with a Live CD and perform this.

Comment: I think it's a **very bad** idea to suggest a claimed "convert anything" tool to a newbie. He might not even understand the fundamental differences of how Unix filesystems and Windows filesystems work! Does he know the execute bit? Does he know that file hiding work differently and there's no Hidden attribute in Unix/Linux?

Comment: @Explorer09 All he need to know to do this is how to type correct command in Linux (I suppose he knows that if he asking about converting to **Linux** file system).

Comment: @PASAf If he knew that already, he won't be bothered to use the tool you suggested and instead properly format a filesystem and copy the files from a backed-up drive. If he wishes _in-place_ conversion, he would better state that _explicitly_ and know all the risks associated with that.

Comment: @Explorer09 I think there is no **right** solution in this case. In my opinion your solution is not suitable for all situations, because not all people in the world who need to convert NTFS to ext4 have two HDDs: one actually they use and one just in case they suddenly come up with idea to swich to Linux.